# Vue - script-setup data to script for charts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

First let me clarify, i'm new to vue.

What I am trying to do is, when I get data from the `defineProps`. I want that the data from the `defineProps` goes to my script. Only I cant get the data over there. It is only available in the `<template> {{ graph }} </template>`. Notice that i can access the data with `{{ graph }}` in there. I just cant find a way to use it in `export default { }`

So my script is looking like this

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['graph']);
</script>

<template>
 {{ graph }} // Works
</template>

<script>
console.log(props); // Doesnt work or
console.log(graph); // Doesnt work
export default {
}
</script>
```

So, how do I get the data from props(graph) into `export default { }`?

Why do I want do this?

I saw https://vue-chartjs.org/examples/ and I followed it.

```
export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March' ],
        datasets: [ { data: [3, 20, 12] } ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the `data: [3, 20, 12]`. I want to edit the values with the data I get. For example `data: [props.day1, props.day2, props.day3]`

Comment: Don't mix `script` and `script setup`, unless you know why you need it. It's either one or another. There's no `props` because it's regular JS, there's no such variable, unless you define it. If you're new, stick to the official guides, they are specific about how a component is structured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like commented, use just `script setup`, try like following:

```
<template>
  <Bar :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
</template>
<script setup>
  import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
  import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

  const chartData = ref({
    labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Data One',
        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
        data: [40, 20, 12]
      }
    ]
  })
  const chartOptions = ref({
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  })
</script>
```

demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-qand6h?file=package.json,src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Awesome man! this did it. And I am understanding now more on how VUE works :). I only needed to edit "maintainAspectRatio: false" to  "maintainAspectRatio: true". The height was only increasing lol.